# Prove a matrix Question by Induction

Tags: matrices, induction

I am struggling with this question. I get to to a certain point and then don't know what to do. So heres what I do.

Given:
A=
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0  \\
        -1 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Proof:
Consider $A^n$ = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2^n & 0  \\
        1-2^n & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

(The Proposition)

(1) When n =1, $A^1$ = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2^1 & 0  \\
        1-2^1 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0  \\
        -1 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ Which is true. That is the proposition is true when n=1.

(2) Assume that the proposition is true when n=k

$A^k$ = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2^k & 0  \\
        1-2^k & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

And i don't know what to do now. I started doing a K+1 proof but it went nowhere.

Comment: I'm not trying to call you out at all, but what happened when you tried the $k+1$ step, what was it that got you stuck?

Comment: well i got to this complicated matrix addition thing and i didn't know how to solve it

Comment: perhaps you should prove a result you know well by induction. so that to get that of the way before you mix induction and matrix algebra. what you seems to be struggling is not this problem but the way proof by induction works.

Comment: In class I can easily do normal induction without matrices. However when matrices were included i started struggling

Answer (score 1):

You just have to prove that the proposition is true for $n=k+1$, for that calculate $A^{k+1} = A^{k}\times A$ with using the fact that the proposition is true for $A^{k}$

Comment: Can i say that is proposition is true for A^k i only proved it is true when n=1

Comment: You proved it for n=1. Now you assume that is true for n=k. There is no need to prove it, it is a supposition. Then, if you succceed to prove that it is still true for n=k+1, you win. Indeed, you proved it for n=1 , and you know that if it is true for n=k, it is true for n=k+1. It is true for n=1 so it is true for n=1+1=2. But then it is also true for n=2+1=3. But then ... it is true for all $n\in \mathbb N$. This works as a ladder!

Answer (score 1):

This is the inductive step: Show that for all $k \geq 1$, we have $$A^{k+1} = A^kA = \left( \begin{matrix} 2^k & 0 \\ 1 - 2^k & 1 \end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) = \ \cdots $$

Fill in the blank by doing the matrix multiplication and show that the resulting matrix has the desired form for $A^{k+1}$.

Comment: Ah so a quick question would it be $$
        \begin{matrix}
        2^k+1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
         \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: You're asking if that is the product of those two matrices? If so, then no.

Comment: Sorry would it equal $$
        \begin{matrix}
        2^k+1 & 0  \\
        1-2^k+1 & 1  \\
        \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: the two +1 should be in the powers